# Why $\langle x|p \rangle$ is momentum eigenstate of which eigenvalue is $p$ at position basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, momentum

I don't understand why $\langle x|p \rangle$ is momentum eigenstate of which eigenvalue is p at position basis. (It appear at Griffiths, Quantum mechanics 3rd, example 3.9)

I'm not sure, but I try thinking about following:

At (time independent) Schrodinger equation and eigen equation ($\hat{H}ψ=Eψ$), $ψ$ is wave function and eigenfunction

At $Ψ(x,t)=\langle x|S(t) \rangle$, $Ψ$ is position space wave function and position component of S(t) at position basis.

Let p is momentum state, then $\langle x|p \rangle$ is momentum eigenstate at position basis.

At $\langle \hat{p}|x|p \rangle=\langle p|x|p \rangle$, $\langle x|p \rangle$ is momentum eigenfunction of which eigenvalue is p.

I think this is too far-fetched.

It's very strange and I think I wrote it wrong since I don't know Dirac notation well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be great if you were comfortable with Dirac notation still I will try my best.

Eigenvalue equation for momentum operator look like:
$$P|p\rangle =p|p\rangle$$
You can compare it with the form:
$$\text{Operator - Vector }\rightarrow \text{Eigenvalue - Vector}$$

If we want to project this on a position basis (That is to say above is written in abstract form we want to write on a position basis) :
$$\langle x|P|p\rangle =p\langle x|p\rangle $$

or
$$-i\hbar \frac{d\psi_p(x)}{dx}=p\psi_p(x)$$
where $\psi_p(x)=\langle x|p\rangle$ is momentum eigen function in position basis with eigenvalue $p$. You can solve above to find
$$\psi_p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}e^{ipx/\hbar}$$

---

Note :
\begin{align*}
\langle x|P|p\rangle &= \int \langle x|P|x'\rangle \langle x'|p\rangle dx' \\
&= \int [-i\hbar \delta'(x-x')]\psi_p(x')dx' \\
&= -i\hbar \frac{d\psi_p(x)}{dx}
\end{align*}

which just demonstrates How the momentum operator looks on in position basis.

Comment: Can I ask question? In the note, why the second and third equalities are true?

Comment: @Plantation Please look into the properties of the Dirac delta function. In particular, try integration by part.

Comment: @ Young Kindaichi : Can I ask more? 1) Why $\langle x | P | x' \rangle = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \langle x| x' \rangle = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(x-x')$? Can the momentum operator $P$ be pulled outside from braket ? Why?  2) Just looking, the notation $\langle x | p \rangle$ seems to mean inner product of position bra vector $\langle x | $ and momentum ket vector $| p \rangle$. And I think that inner product is number. And how can we set $\langle x | p \rangle$ as a function $\psi_{p}(x)$?

Comment: (1)  The form of the matrix element of $P$ in position basis is sometimes considered as a Postulate of QM. See R. Shankar Chapter 4.  But you can derive them assuming the commutation relation between $X$ and $P$. (2) In $\langle x|p\rangle $, $x$ and $p$ are assumed to be continuous variables; therefore, the inner product is written as a function.

Answer (score 2):

What he means is that $|p\rangle$ is the momentum eigenstate with eigenvalue $p$, i.e. $\hat{p}|p\rangle=p|p\rangle$, where $\hat{p}$ is the momentum operator and $p$ the eigenvalue. Then $\langle x|p\rangle$ is the $|p\rangle$ eigenstate expressed in the position basis.

Hope this helps.